# Draggable has different Offset values for onDragUpdate and onDragEnd / onDragCanceled

Tags: flutter

Why do I get such different values for the update, and the final drag callbacks? I can't figure out why they are different, and the amount they are different isn't constant or linear (although `onDragEnd` is always smaller).

I'm using `onDragEnd` in this example, but the offset from `onDragCanceled` was the same as `onDragEnd`.

```dart
Draggable(
  axis: Axis.vertical,
  dragAnchorStrategy: childDragAnchorStrategy,
  maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
  data: 1,
  feedback: const SizedBox.shrink(),
  child: _CustomWidget(widget.selected),
  onDragUpdate: (details) { // DragUpdateDetails
    details.localPosition; // y is from 812.0 to 814.0 on the last ~5 callbacks before onDragEnd
    // ... do something
  },
  onDragEnd: (details) { // DraggableDetails
    details.offset); // y -> 794.9
    // ... do something
  },
)
```